# Reposition to zero after hiding segments in bokeh stacked bar chart

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to use the `click_policy` functionality of a vertically stacked bar chart in bokeh to hide/show different segments of the bar chart and for the remaining segments to be aligned at y=0 (shifted down to the x-axis). That is, given the example code below, I would like to click on 2015 in the legend and then it would hide the lowest segment and shift the remaining segments down to the x-axis again. So the bars would start at zero and show the two remaining segments. Would I need to add a callback function for that and how would I do that?

Many thanks!

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("stacked.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(years, x='fruits', width=0.9, color=colors, source=data,
             legend=[value(x) for x in years])

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.2 there is nothing built-in that would support connecting the interactive legend `"hide"` feature to a re-computation of the the stackers for a set of vbar glyphs. I can't think of any hacky or workaround solutions, either, since there is no event to hook into when a glyph is hidden using an interactive legend. Adjusting the the stackers would be somewhat problematic too, regardless of that. Since each successive vbar glyphs builds on all the previous levels, *all* the vbar stack transforms would need to be updated appropriately.

At this time I can only suggest that you make a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) around supporting this kind of use-case better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @bigreddot. This was my impression too, but wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything.